# Job fail when uploading file from system to stream in Azure Media Service

Tags: node.js, azure-media-services

I'm trying to set a VOD service on Azure media service using node.js, but job fails to reach file from container.

This is for a Linux server running node v10. The Azure tutorial for node works for sample URL, but not for a file from the system. The file gets stored in a input blob container but don't go past that.

When running the AMS tutorial, without a change, for node to get the streaming endpoints for a sample video from a URL from the tutorial I got the endpoints for stream, but when trying to upload a file from my system to the Azure media service, the file gets uploaded to a blob container, but the job apparently fails to find the video in the input asset container and returns a `ErrorDownloadingInputAssetServiceFailure` error, with message that says that :

> File does not exist in the container:
>   2019-09-05T05:36:10.775Z-big_buck_bunny_480p_2mb.mp431 \nContainer
>   files: 10.775Z-big_buck_bunny_480p_2mb.mp431

I don't know where I'm getting this wrong, but from the message seems that the job is trying to find the file in a blob container that don't exists.

EDIT:
Tutorial link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-nodejs-quickstart
Tutorial GitHub: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials.git
My GitHub for this code: https://github.com/DiegoAntonioli/azure-test.git

I'm using multer as a middleware to get the files, so i'm saving the files in the system through multer and uploading to a blob container on azure.
The file in the input asset blob container gets saved with the name i'm looking for "2019-09-05T05:36:10.775Z-big_buck_bunny_480p_2mb.mp431", and not the name that says in the error message "10.775Z-big_buck_bunny_480p_2mb.mp431".

EDIT 2:
Problem solved, seems that the azure searches for files in the blob container without the ":" character, so when i was uploading with a isosstring date in the start they looked for the file with the name only after the last ":" character, so it would never find the file. I don't know if it is in the documentation, but if it is they should make it clearer, because i was lost looking for my error and it was only the file name.

Comment: Can you share the tutorial link

Comment: Please also share the code you are using to upload a file. There is a mismatch between the file names that the service is looking for, and the actual file in the Storage container. For the case above, the service is looking for "2019-09-05T05:36:10.775Z-big_buck_bunny_480p_2mb.mp431". And the file that is actually preset seems to be "10.775Z-big_buck_bunny_480p_2mb.mp431". Also, what you would want to have uploaded is a file named "big_buck_bunny_480p_2mb.mp4", without a prefix/suffix.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, had to give attention to a work project. I edited the question with the info both of you asked for @MohitVerma and AnilMurching

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that the blob/file name had an unsupported character ':'. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/assets-concept#naming-blobs%20,) page for the restrictions on allowed names. However, your post did reveal a bug in how we were unpacking the error message - that bug has been handed off to engineering to fix in an upcoming sprint.

Comment: If i may add just one comment, maybe you shouldn't let the file get stored and send the error message when one tries to upload the file to the container with one of the reserved characters, just so that person knows that the file name have such character. Thanks for the help